# Making all class methods call the same function

Tags: c++, logging, methods, function-calls

So, I've got this situation:

```
#include "ActionLog.h"
class Library{
        ActionLog aLog;
        // ... the rest of it is private, mind you :D
    public:
        Library(...);
        void addBook(...);
        void removeBook(...);
        // ... aaand there's a whole bunch of these :)
    };
```

Now, `class ActionLog` has a public method `void log(...);`. It should, once implemented, record the beginning of any activity listed as a method of `class Library` (*and eventually it's success/failure, which is optional*).

**I'm wondering this:** Is there some more elegant way of making every `class Library`'s method call the `aLog.log(...);` method when/before it starts executing? By "elegant" I mean other than just calling it explicitly in every single method...

I **am** aware of the [Python version of the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998969/how-to-make-every-class-method-call-a-specified-method-before-execution) for the similar problem, but I'm not familiar with Python, so I'm not even sure that the same class-related principles apply.

Comment: This certainly sounds like a good case to look into a decorator pattern

Comment: I did :) And I think I might use some of those ideas for flexible library searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't have any means of reflection built-in. There's no way to list methods neither in runtime, nor in compile-time. The best you can do is to hide logging into some `#define` that you will use to define every method, but preprocessor usage is an antipattern in modern C++.

Stick to the current approach.

Comment: Even the current approach relies on `__FUNCTION__`, as a help for distinguishing `class Library`'s methods...

Answer (score 1):

As polkovnikov.ph said, without reflection you wouldn't be able to use the python's approach to this.

Just for fun I am going to leave this here but I wouldn't recommend its use:

```
#include <iostream>    

class Logger
{
    public:
        void log(std::string entry)
        {
            std::cout << entry << std::endl;
        }
};    

class A
{
    Logger mylog;
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "Doing foo" << std::endl;
        }    

        Logger& getLogger()
        {
            return mylog;
        }
};    

#define CALL_FUNC_AND_LOG(obj,func) \
    { obj.getLogger().log("Logging "#func); obj.func(); }    

int main()
{
    A a;
    CALL_FUNC_AND_LOG(a,foo);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/q0VHj6

Or another version that automatically logs the end of scope of the method.

```
#include <iostream>    

class Logger
{
    std::string _entry;
    public:
        Logger(std::string entry)
        {
            _entry = entry;
            std::cout << "Starting execution of " << entry << std::endl;
        }    

        ~Logger()
        {
            std::cout << "Ending execution of " << _entry << std::endl;
        }
};    

class A
{
    public:
        void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "Doing foo" << std::endl;
        }
};    

#define CALL_FUNC_AND_LOG(obj,func) \
    { \
        Logger _mylogger(""#func); \
        obj.func(); \
        \
    }

int main()
{
    A a;
    CALL_FUNC_AND_LOG(a,foo);
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DHf3xu