# Call an instance method after any method of that class is called in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, the same way unit_test works - the way when I call a method test_square, the method setup is called before it and the method teardown is called afterwards.

How can that be done with a custom class?

So I have a class called user
and I want to make a method user.do_stuff be called every time any method of user is called.

Comment: You could just call it in every function. You could also make it a decorator and decorate each function.

Comment: A decorator would give it a nice touch, because then any other instance method that needs to use this feature, you can just "decorate" it with that added feature.

Comment: Have a look at this: [How to make every Class Method call a specified method before execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998969/how-to-make-every-class-method-call-a-specified-method-before-execution)